# issue with circuit breaker and AbstractCloudConfig when upgrading to spring boot 2.0.3

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, circuit-breaker

Currently we are upgrading our app to use **spring boot 2.0.3**.
The app is deployed to PCF and uses circuit breaker, also we use AbstractCloudConfig in our code in order to initialize a session and retrieve the properties for cassandra from the user provided service.
We noticed that when checking the health using [actuator/health](https://dummy) , rabbit fails and the cause is due to connection refused.
It's trying to connect to [localhost](http://localhost) instead of the host provided by the rabbit service in pcf.
After testing and debugging the app , we came to a conclusion that the issue is due to `AbstractCloudConfig`.
In order to verify this conclusion , we created a demo app that uses circuit breaker and also `AbstractCloudConfig` and we noticed the same issue, When we removed the use of AbstractCloudConfig everything was fine.

Is there a different way to use `AbstractCloudConfig` in spring boot 2.0.3 or this is an issue?

```
${spring.boot.version} = 2.0.3.RELEASE
```

**Dependencies in pom.xml:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Kay-SR8</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>


    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-circuit-breaker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>






        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**CloudCassandraConnectionConfig class:**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class CloudCassandraConnectionConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig
{   

}
```